# Default implementation of protocol method with Swift extension

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, swift-extensions, protocol-extension

I'm trying to write default behaviour for a delegate method using a Swift extension as below, but it is never called. Does anyone know why or how to do it the right way?

```
extension NSURLSessionDelegate {

    public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
        //default behaviour here
    }
}
```

Adding `override` does not work either.

According to [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSURLSession.swift), 
Apple's default implementation looks like:

```
extension NSURLSessionDelegate {
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?) { }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) { }
}
```

My DataTask calls typically look like this:

```
let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
let requestURL = NSURL(string:"https:www.google.com/blabla")

session.dataTaskWithURL(requestURL!, completionHandler: completion).resume()
```

Where `completion` will typically be a Swift closure received via parameter.

I need to implement the `URLSession(... didReceiveChallenge ...)` function for all `nsurlsessiontask` implementations throughout my app, but can't set my session's delegate as I need to use the completionHandler (as mentioned in my comment below).

Comment: If you implements your method in your delegate, is the method ever called ? Maybe the delegate methods are not called either way. Otherwise your implementation looks fine.

Comment: I'm using `dataTaskWithURL` with a completionHandler (which I can't change to manage via delegate for other reasons), so I can't set a specific delegate for my `NSURLSession` when creating the session - else the completionHandler isn't called. See also my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extends the `NSURLSessionDelegate` protocol for adding default implementation, but your `NSURLSession` objects needs a delegate.

This delegate can only be set using `+sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:` (since the delegate property is [read only](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSession/delegate)), so your only way to set it is to subclass `NSURLSession`, override  `+sessionWithConfiguration:` and call the initializer with the delegate property.  The issue here is that you have to replace all your `NSURLSession` objects to `MyCustomSessionClass`. objects.

I suggest you to create a SessionCreator class which will conforms to `NSURLSessionDelegate` protocol and will create `NSURLSession`objects. You still have to replace the creation of your objects, but at least the object isn't the delegate of itself.

```
public class SessionCreator:NSObject,NSURLSessionDelegate {

    //MARK: - Singleton method    
    class var sharedInstance :SessionCreator {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = SessionCreator()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    //MARK: - Public class method    
    public class func createSessionWithConfiguration (configuration:NSURLSessionConfiguration) -> NSURLSession {
        return sharedInstance.createSessionWithConfiguration(configuration)
    }

    //MARK: - Private methods
    private func createSessionWithConfiguration (configuration:NSURLSessionConfiguration) -> NSURLSession {
        return NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }

    //MARK: - NSURLSessionDelegate protocol conformance
    public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
        // Always called since it's the delegate of all NSURLSession created using createSessionWithConfiguration
    }
}

// Let create a NSURLSession object :
let session = SessionCreator.createSessionWithConfiguration(NSURLSessionConfiguration())
```

Comment: You can extends the NSURLSessionDelegate protocol for adding default implementation, but your NSURLSession objects needs a delegate. Nailed it.